# Why does scikit-learn in Anaconda shows cv="warn" in "validation_curve" type signature?

Tags: linux, macos, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I noticed a difference between installs of Anaconda on Linux vs MacOS.
Each shows different default values for the `cv` parameter for validation_curve.
Linux shows `cv=None` but MacOS shows an odd `cv="warn"`.
I see no explanation of `cv="warn"` in the scikit-learn docs
nor have I found anything useful from online searching.

What does `cv="warn"` signify? Is this problematic?

I also see that `error_score=nan` on Linux but `error_score='raise-deprecating'` on MacOS.

Does this alteration of parameters arise from different version numbers of Anaconda or from the OS?

I get the same type signature from `?` operator in Jupyter notebooks.

-------------- Linux --------------

```
Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 19:59:22) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from sklearn.model_selection import validation_curve
>>> help(validation_curve)
Help on function validation_curve in module sklearn.model_selection._validation:

validation_curve(estimator, X, y, param_name, param_range, groups=None, cv=None, scoring=None, n_jobs=None, pre_dispatch='all', verbose=0, error_score=nan)
    Validation curve. ...
```

-------------- MacOS --------------

```
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019, 15:17:50) 
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from sklearn.model_selection import validation_curve
>>> help(validation_curve)
Help on function validation_curve in module sklearn.model_selection._validation:

validation_curve(estimator, X, y, param_name, param_range, groups=None, cv='warn', scoring=None, n_jobs=None, pre_dispatch='all', verbose=0, error_score='raise-deprecating')
    Validation curve. ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the two versions of scikit-learn (on Linux and MacOS) are different. As per the [PR#11557](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/11557), the default CV (kfold cross-validation) value was changed from 3 to 5. The `warn` is used in scikit-learn to show warning when the default value of a parameter is changed. Read more from the scikit-learn developer [contributions documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/dev/developers/contributing.html#change-the-default-value-of-a-parameter).

For example,

> If the default value of a parameter needs to be changed, please replace the default value with a specific value (e.g., warn) and raise `FutureWarning` when users are using the default value. In the following example, we change the default value of `n_clusters` from 5 to 10 (current version is 0.20).

```
import warnings

def example_function(n_clusters='warn'):
    if n_clusters == 'warn':
        warnings.warn("The default value of n_clusters will change from "
                      "5 to 10 in 0.22.", FutureWarning)
        n_clusters = 5
```